# How to set the default value of an attribute on a Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to set the default value of an attribute on a Laravel model?

Should I set the default when creating a migration or should I set it in the model class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747500/how-to-set-a-default-attribute-value-for-a-laravel-eloquent-model

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can set Default attribute in  Model also>

```
protected $attributes = [
        'status' => self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED,
        'role_id' => self::ROLE_PUBLISHER,
    ];
```

You can find the details in these links

1.) [How to set a default attribute value for a Laravel / Eloquent model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747500/how-to-set-a-default-attribute-value-for-a-laravel-eloquent-model)

2.) https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-help-generating-attribute-values-before-creating-record

---

You can also Use **Accessors & Mutators** for this
You can find the details in the Laravel documentation
1.) https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

2.) https://scotch.io/tutorials/automatically-format-laravel-database-fields-with-accessors-and-mutators

3.) [Universal accessors and mutators in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482310/universal-accessors-and-mutators-in-laravel-4)

Comment: thanks, setting default attribute works fine as 

protected $attributes = [
        'status' => self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED,
        'role_id' => self::ROLE_PUBLISHER,
    ];

but as Mutators it didn't work e.g.

public function setUserTypeAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['user_type'] = 'User';
}

i want to ask if there is any difference b/w these approaches, or which one is best.

Comment: Both are better. Its up to you. In mutator i gave you an example where you can set default value in case of `empty or custom` made condition.like 

`public function setUserTypeAttribute($value){ $this->attributes['user_type'] = empty($value) ? 'User' : $value;  }`

I hope you got my point with this example.

Comment: @Zeeshan Bin Iqbal Did this solve your issue?

Comment: Using a mutator won't quite work because the mutator only gets called when you assign a value to the attribute. So if you never assign a value to that attribute at all, it won't actually have the default value that you want it to.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice.

Comment: @Mauro Your appreciation is more than any up vote. Thanx

Comment: Well, theoretically setting default values in database will improve performance slightly, but it is too little to be even taken into consideration. If you delare them in the model, it will also be used while creating a new model instance for eg. when using a make() statement. So use it based on your requirements.

Answer (score 54):

The other answers are not working for me - they may be outdated. This is what I used as my solution for auto setting an attribute:

```
/**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // auto-sets values on creation
    static::creating(function ($query) {
        $query->is_voicemail = $query->is_voicemail ?? true;
    });
}
```

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: I should also specify that I try to use default values in migrations. This example above is from a Voicemail model which is extending a Recording model, so they use the same table. When a new Voicemail model is created, is_voicemail is set to true.

Comment: i just needed to set a value IF it comes through on create as null, so this worked great for me

Comment: This is a great solution for the insanity of not being able to set a default value of a blank string for a text column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: Nice solution. Where can I find documentation of this?

Comment: @nishilbhave  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L212            https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events

Comment: Smartest thing I've seen on stackoverflow up to now!

Comment: Very nice. This answer also handles the situation where you want to assign default values that are complex and computed, for example, a `UUID` string since you can't assign the value of `Str::uuid()` directly into the `$attributes` property.

Answer (score 12):

You should set default values in [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#column-modifiers):

```
$table->tinyInteger('role')->default(1);
```

Comment: For example, when using models for form validation you want to have a default value before saving it to the database. When using your example, you need to add the record to the database before being able to retrieve the default value, which is cumbersome.

Comment: Not to mention that _some_ column types don't allow defaults (such as text)

Comment: The question asks, how to set the default value on a model. It does not ask how to set the default value in the database. These are different things, and many times you may want to `new` a model without reference to the database

Comment: Whereas this may be the appropriate best practice for a RDBMS, the OP doesn't specify which database he is using. In a schemaless setup, this doesn't apply.

Comment: Some RDBMSs (e.g. MySQL < 8.0) only support constants as default value for a field, with no support for expressions. Imagine you have a _year_ field and you would like the default value to be the current year. In such case your best option is probably to use application code (Laravel model), to supply that default value.

Comment: in migrations is the best place if it's a static value. For calculated values, the boot method is the way to go

Comment: You might need to add a "->change()" to the end of this line, like this:
$table->tinyInteger('role')->default(1)->change()