# How to return a default column value for mass assignment of a model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using mass assignment to create a server model like so:

```
/** @var Model $server */
$server = Server::create($request->all());

return response($server->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
```

Now my server also has a `status` property which maps to a MySQL `status` column which has a default value of 0 in MySQL.

Because the status is not being set implicitly in my request attributes(no need since the default is fine) it does not return the `status` property on the model. It will return all of the properties in my `$request->all()` though. These are validated and coming from a form.

How can I return my full `$server` model including the default value for `status`? I am forced to fire off another query to re-fetch the model I have just created, just so I can also include the `status` property with the MySQL default?

Comment: Possible duplicate [how-to-set-the-default-value-of-an-attribute-on-a-laravel-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912372/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-an-attribute-on-a-laravel-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't do a selecet after an insert so you wont get any values that the DB has to set itself. You can refresh the model instance though (cause it to select that row):

```
$model->refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning it as `JSON`, you can add `status` to `protected $appends = ["status"];`

```
class Server extends Model {
   protected $appends = ["status"];
   ...
}
```

That way, even if you don't set `status` in your `Server::create()` method, it *should* still be visible in your `JSON` response as `server.status`. Also, perhaps adjust your return to

```
return response()->json(["server" => $server], 200); // or whatever HTTP code you need.
```

Since `$appends` only works with `accessors`, perhaps use `$request->merge()` to "fill in the gaps" for data you want returned in your JSON response:

```
$request->merge([
  "status" => "active", // Or whatever the default is from the database
  ...
]);
```

Since the response is returning everything in `$request->all()`, merge it with default values from MySQL. Note: currently hardcoded, would need to be updated if migration/schema changed, or via SQL command to get defaults.

Comment: Appends only work for `accessors` though and it does not grab the default value which is specified within MySQL.

Comment: Hmm... That's unfortunate, but makes sense now that you say it. I haven't run into this specific issue, but I have been doing a lot of JSON returns recently (API stuff). Could you do a `$request->merge(["status" => "default_status_from_db"]);`? That _should_ make `status` attribute available to your `$server` model. Would have to be updated if the default in the DB changed though, so maybe not the best approach.

Comment: This works but like you said it is still prone to error. Thanks for thinking along though this seems like this is a pretty good solution.

Comment: Perhaps update the answer? The current answer does not work for the question and only works with accessors.