# Create user in Laravel with custom fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I am trying to create a user in laravel using laravel's own auth function. 
I have enabled it and want to add some of my own values to fields in the users table.

Right now I get this error, but dont know how to fix it. Any ideas? :

Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `activation_token`, `is_active`, `is_expert`, `is_flag`, `is_subscriber`, `profile_img`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Henrik Tobiassen, tarzan@hotmail.com, $2y$10$.xmKCnSdC8vogY47mbwRVOVehXJIedLMJ/gpfNgluPR9QpOtgyJ1m, 4633, 0, 0, 0, 0, uploads/profile_pics/default.jpg, 2019-03-10 21:12:29, 2019-03-10 21:12:29)

App/user.php

```
 /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'password', 'remember_token', 'activation_token', 'is_active', 'is_expert', 'is_flag', 'is_subscriber', 'profile_img',
    ];
```

RegisterController

```
 /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],


        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'activation_token' => [rand(1000, 9999)],
            'is_active' => '0',
            'is_expert' => '0',
            'is_flag' => '0',
            'is_subscriber' => '0',
            'profile_img' => 'uploads/profile_pics/default.jpg',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You could have also used `protected $attributes = [...]` or **Accessors & Mutators** to set default the values instead of editing **RegisterController** - see more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912500/3226121). This way, your logic would apply to any user that is created in the application, and not just register user...

Answer (score 2):

This might be happening because you're sending an array instead of a number or string to activation_token field.

So instead of

```php
'activation_token' => [rand(1000,9999)],
```

do

```php
'activation_token' => rand(1000,9999),
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely the reason is you have made your random variable an array. Remove the square brackets around it. This will now return a string rather than an array.

Check the example at the bottom for a demonstration.

**Corrected code:**

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'activation_token' => rand(1000, 9999),
        'is_active' => '0',
        'is_expert' => '0',
        'is_flag' => '0',
        'is_subscriber' => '0',
        'profile_img' => 'uploads/profile_pics/default.jpg',
    ]);
}
```

**Example:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1977ba4dbe2f22870e0e81a628749c39c367747a

Comment: That was it. So simple. Thank you guys

Comment: @htobiassen Perfect! Often it's the small things!

Answer (score 1):

seems you are trying to send an array

```
'activation_token' => [rand(1000,9999)]
```

instead of string/number

Fix ->

```
'activation_token' => rand(1000,9999),
```