# "error": "array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

when I am trying to create a new order this errors appears:

`"error": "array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given"`

and here the whole function that I am trying to create a new order with it, I tried it like for 20 times and it worked fine, but after a time it stopped working with the above error

```
public function placeOrder()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->id();

        try {
            $cart = Cart::where('client_id', '=', $user_id)->first();

            $cartDetails = CartDetail::where('cart_id', '=', $cart->id)->get();
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return response()->json(["error" =>$e->getMessage()]);
        }

        try {
            foreach ($cartDetails as $cartDetail){
                $item = StoreItem::where('item_id', '=', $cartDetail->item_id)->first();
                $this->items_total += $cartDetail->quantity;
                $discountedPrice =  ($item->unit_price * $item->discount) / 100;
                $this->total_amount += $cartDetail->quantity * $discountedPrice;
            }
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return response()->json(["error" =>$e->getMessage()]);
        }

        if(count($cartDetails->toArray()) == 0){
            return response()->json(["warning" => "Please Add Cart Items"]);
        }

        $storeId = $cartDetails[0]->store_id;
        try {
            $store = Store::findOrFail($storeId);

            $address = Address::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('is_default', '=', true)->first();
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return response()->json(["error" => $e->getMessage()]);
        }

        $delivery_charge = 2;

        $final_total = $this->total_amount + $delivery_charge;

        $address_id = $address->id;

        try {

            $data = [
                'items_total' => $this->items_total,
                'total_amount' => $this->total_amount,
                'is_paid' => false,
                'delivery_charge' => $delivery_charge,
                'shopper_earning' => $delivery_charge / 1.5,
                'final_total' => $final_total,
                'client_id' => $user_id,
                'store_id' => $store->id,
                'address_id' => $address_id,
                'currency_id' => $store->currency_id
            ];

            $createdOrder = Order::create($data);


            if ($createdOrder){
                foreach ($cartDetails as $cartDetail){
                    $cartDetail->delete();
                }
                event(new CartUpdated($cart->id, $user_id));
            }

            return response()->json(['success' => $createdOrder]);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return response()->json(["error" =>$e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

when I tried to debug it, the error is within the `Order::create($data);`

why this error appears?

**EDIT:**

Debug Console:

```
{
    "message": "array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php",
    "line": 78,
    "trace": [
        {
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php",
            "line": 78,
            "function": "array_merge"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php",
            "line": 64,
            "function": "getPayloadFromEvent",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php",
            "line": 33,
            "function": "call_user_func_array"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php",
            "line": 36,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php",
            "line": 91,
            "function": "unwrapIfClosure",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Util",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php",
            "line": 35,
            "function": "callBoundMethod",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
            "line": 592,
            "function": "call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php",
            "line": 94,
            "function": "call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php",
            "line": 98,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php",
            "line": 114,
            "function": "dispatchNow",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php",
            "line": 289,
            "function": "queue",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php",
            "line": 212,
            "function": "broadcastEvent",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/PendingBroadcast.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
            "line": 218,
            "function": "__destruct",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\PendingBroadcast",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/app/Observers/OrderStatusObserver.php",
            "line": 15,
            "function": "broadcast"
        },
        {
            "function": "created",
            "class": "App\\Observers\\OrderStatusObserver",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php",
            "line": 388,
            "function": "call_user_func_array"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php",
            "line": 218,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php",
            "line": 188,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 886,
            "function": "fireModelEvent",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 728,
            "function": "performInsert",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 767,
            "function": "save",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php",
            "line": 433,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 768,
            "function": "tap"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "create",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 1728,
            "function": "forwardCallTo",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 1740,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/app/Http/Controllers/Api/OrderController.php",
            "line": 108,
            "function": "__callStatic",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "function": "placeOrder",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\OrderController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "call_user_func_array"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/sohaib/Desktop/Final-Project/Discounts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 239,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

this is about the half but I think its enough, so I created before a class called **OrderStatusObserver**, Honestly, I didn't know how this works, but this class contains this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Events\OrderStatus;
use App\Order;

class OrderStatusObserver
{
    public function created(Order $order)
    {
       broadcast(new OrderStatus($order));
    }
}
```

this is my broadcastWith function in OrderStatus Event:

```
public function broadcastWith()
    {
        if($this->order->status == 'accepted'){
            return ['current_position' => 2, 'id' => $this->order->id];
        }elseif ($this->order->status == 'inprogress'){
            return ['current_position' => 3];
        }elseif ($this->order->status == 'onway'){
            return ['current_position' => 4];
        }elseif ($this->order->status == 'delivered'){
            return ['current_position' => 5];
        }
    }
```

and when I commented `broadcast(new OrderStatus($order));` this line it works fine, so anyone knows what is the problem with this, hope anyone can help and sorry for my english

Comment: Please provide a full stack log of error

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi Nothing more `array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given`, I am trying to debug it, but only this line appears.

Comment: are you using ajax?

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi no, I edited it, hope now is more helpful

Comment: you try to send json output, if you are using ajax, try to set `APP_DEBUG` to true and you will see debug trace in response

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi I am using react native on the front end and I am running it with expo, so it's somewhat hard to debug on its console, I am trying to debug the API using postman. but did you mean that the problem is with the returning?

Comment: you should set debug in laravel config, and then you will see more detail about error in postman

Comment: `APP_DEBUG=true` in env file

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi I edit it so you can see the debug console

Comment: Can you provilde `OrderStatus` class content? there is a problem with boardcastWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you use array _merge() in your create method. Can you show us this one? Also you can check if $data is not null before send it to your method.

just to explain why I am asking you to share your `OrderStatus` class: 
according to your error trace, the problem come from the function `getPayloadFromEvent` in `BroadcastEvent.php` :

```
protected function getPayloadFromEvent($event)
{
    if (method_exists($event, 'broadcastWith')) {
        return array_merge(
            $event->broadcastWith(), ['socket' => data_get($event, 'socket')]
        );
    }

    $payload = [];

    foreach ((new ReflectionClass($event))->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $property) {
        $payload[$property->getName()] = $this->formatProperty($property->getValue($event));
    }

    unset($payload['broadcastQueue']);

    return $payload;
}
```

exactly in the array_merge call:

```
return array_merge($event->broadcastWith(), ['socket' => data_get($event, 'socket')]);
```

so as your error message says `"array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given"`, the broadcastWith in your case is returning null instead of an array.

Comment: I checked $data, it is not null, how do you know that I am using array_merge()??? I didn't see it before

Comment: It's in the error message so it's somewhere. Can you past the code of create?

Comment: its a built-in function in Laravel

Comment: Are you sure? Which version?

Comment: Laravel version 7.x

Comment: I think that placeOrder is a function in your controller that calls the Order model. Can you please give me the line calling that model?

Comment: I found the problem after debugging but I didn't know why this happens, I created before a class called `OrderStatusObserver` and contains a function that get the order as parameter and `broadcast(new  OrderStatus($order))` as an event when I commented this line it works fine, I didn't now why!!!!

Comment: did you execute `composer dump-autoload` ? if not please do it.

Comment: what do you have in `App\Events\OrderStatus` ?

Comment: if you don't have a broadcastWith function in OrderStatus class, add a new one like: `public function broadcastWith()
{
    return ['message' => 'Order created'];
}`

Comment: Also I have all the important functions, like `broadcastOn` and `broadcastWith`

Comment: Thank you Hicham, the error is in `broadcastWith()`, I used if cases, and in every if I returned an array but I missed to add a return if the condition doesn't match any of those if cases, so I added a return. Thank you for help another time :)

Comment: I will add the OrderStatus Event in my question, try to update your answer to be more obvious, thank you.

Comment: please check it now

Comment: glad to hear that you solved your problem. just a note, I think it's better to use a case statement instead of ifs in your function with the default condition.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because of `broadCastWith` So you should Return an array in this method.
You have two problem.

1-in boradCastWith you only check the value of `status`, and there is no fallback code. so in this situation if your status not one of `delivered,onway,inprogress,accepted` you got a problem

```
public function broadcastWith()
{
    if($this->order->status == 'accepted'){
        return ['current_position' => 2, 'id' => $this->order->id];
    }elseif ($this->order->status == 'inprogress'){
        return ['current_position' => 3];
    }elseif ($this->order->status == 'onway'){
        return ['current_position' => 4];
    }elseif ($this->order->status == 'delivered'){
        return ['current_position' => 5];
    }

    return []; // this is a important line
}
```

Also note you may use switch case instead of `elseif`

2-You handle these 4 status probably because other type of status is not valid. So you should add validation.
Also in your code you don't have any value for status, so you should add a default value for it. look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912500/1827594

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I have a `broadcastWith` method in my event.
Inside this I have a value for broadcast like this:

```
return 'say hello to world!';
```

because of this message, `Laravel` returns an error for `array_marge`.

when I change it to this :

```
return ['say hello to world!'];
```

It works but I get my message in array format.

I changed it to this:

```
return ['message' => 'say hello to world'];
```

now I get the message like this in `json` format:

```
{message:say hello to world}
```